# Elasticsearch Installation Issue: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: windows, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am following this website https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html to install elasticsearch in my Ubuntu subsystem for use in Flask application.

However when I tried doing the following commands,

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.8.0-amd64.deb
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.8.0-amd64.deb.sha512
shasum -a 512 -c elasticsearch-7.8.0-amd64.deb.sha512 
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-7.8.0-amd64.deb
```

It returns `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down.`

Similarly, when I followed this page https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-elasticsearch-ubuntu, the same errors returned after `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service` is input.

I am quite new to programming and so I am not very familar on how all these errors/warnings mean and how I can solve it. I have searched around and see that `systemctl` could not be used in the Windows Ubuntu. However, none of the solutions appears to work for me.

May I get some advice on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved! Used `sudo service elasticsearch start` instead will activate elasticsearch.

Comment: muy bien! gracias!!